# How to fill with dots in a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a view with dotted background in android. Any insight please on how I could achieve this...

Please note: I do not want to put a dotted image in background, as one textview is there below the view.

Edit: Seems stackoverflow is voting negetive for this question, dear stackoverflow, I  am very new to android, and hence asking this question, might look silly to the experts but as a beginner I really didn't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service; it is a question and answer site and “I really didn't know how to achieve this” is not a question. What exactly are you stuck on? Do you not have a Java compiler? You know nothing about Android at all? You haven't started? You need to learn and start on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to achive this through the `tileMode`.

put this image file on your drawable folder

[image]

then

**drawable/dot_background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/actual_pattern_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

then set this xml as background on your view

hope this will help help you

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this [Github Library](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator)

You can define page indicator in XML and use it with Viewpager